# onmouseover, onmouseout. Не изменяют элемент

Tags: php, javascript, css

Добрый день! подскажите как реализовать смену картинки при наведении, вот мой нынешний код, но он не работает:

```
<php
$Image = '/image/'.$row['image'];
$Image2 = '/image/'.$row['image2'];
?>
<img src="<?echo $Image;?>" alt"image"
 onmouseover="this.scr='<?echo $Image2 ?>'"
 onmouseout="this.scr='<?echo $Image ?>'">
```

Comment: `onmouseover="this.scr='<?echo $Image2 ?>'"` => **this.src**, а не this.scr

Comment: Прошу прощение за невнимательность. Пол дня голову ломал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<img id="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS7RxMBcEplU5w3MpfIXdlm7Iwsn2OVCwD6JaEd2XvVvGu8WzsU2w"
     onmouseover="this.src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTJMaenY_EGpd7uez2-t5dn_LBd6UHCgIx6NYdFE_1SWjlLF47e'"
     onmouseout="this.src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS7RxMBcEplU5w3MpfIXdlm7Iwsn2OVCwD6JaEd2XvVvGu8WzsU2w'"
     alt="" />
```

Т.е. твой код будет таким:

```
<php
   $Image = '/image/'.$row['image'];
   $Image2 = '/image/'.$row['image2'];
?>
<img src="<?echo $Image;?>" alt"image"
 onmouseover="this.src='<?echo $Image2 ?>'"
 onmouseout="this.src='<?echo $Image ?>'">
```

Answer (score -1):

Был невнимателен, вот конечный результат:

```
<php
$Image = '/image/'.$row['image'];
$Image2 = '/image/'.$row['image2'];
?>
<img src="<?echo $Image;?>" alt"image"
 onmouseover="this.src='<?echo $Image2 ?>'"
 onmouseout="this.src='<?echo $Image ?>'">
```